# SSIS max logic check working but taking longer time to migrate data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating a SSIS package that queries a stored procedure and stores the result set into a table. This table will contain the resultset of 18 billion records. Since I don't have any unique key column, I have dynamically created a rowno column while querying the stored procedure which I am storing in the destination table.

I have created an Execute SQL task that will get the max of the destination table and filter the source with the max so that I transfer only the delta with each migration. I can see that the max logic is working and only the delta gets migrated however I feel that the migration is slow event though there is no data to be transmitted.

Not sure what the problem is? I can see that though there is no data it takes the same amount of time to complete the process event though there is no data.

Here is the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         rowno = row_number() OVER (order by (SELECT NULL))  , 
         fp.companyid,
         fd.dataitemid,
         di.dataitemname,   
         fd.dataitemvalue,
         fu.unittypevalue,
         fp.fiscalyear, fp.fiscalquarter,
         fi.periodenddate, fi.filingdate,
         rt.restatementtypename,
         fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag, fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag,
         conv.currencyconversionflag,
         cur.currencyname, 
         pt.periodtypename
     FROM
         ciqfinperiod fp 
     INNER JOIN 
         CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.MarketDataTemp1 a ON a.companyId = fp.companyid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqperiodtype pt ON pt.periodtypeid = fp.periodtypeid 
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqfininstance fi ON fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
     LEFT JOIN
         ciqrestatementtype rt ON rt.restatementtypeid = fi.restatementtypeid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqfininstancetocollection ic ON ic.financialinstanceid = fi.financialinstanceid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqfincollection fc ON fc.financialcollectionid = ic.financialcollectionid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqfincollectiondata fd ON fd.financialcollectionid = fc.financialcollectionid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqdataitemconversionrule conv ON conv.dataitemid = fd.dataitemid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqcurrency cur ON cur.currencyid = fc.currencyid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqdataitem di ON di.dataitemid= fd.dataitemid
     INNER JOIN 
         ciqfinunittype fu ON fu.unittypeid = fd.unittypeid) q
WHERE
    q.rowno > @maxrowno
```

The max logic that is called by the execute task

```
select COUNT_BIG(rowno) as rowno 
from [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinancialStatementIds]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you can't trust the order of rows. So, for that perspective you should find at least one time-marker to filtering your data. 
Your current problem is that the SQL Server must execute the whole query to be able to count the rows and then do filtering.
Have you seen execution plan of the query?
So summarizing: you have limited amount of sending data, but the server on source-side is reading tons of data. That's why this takes so long.

Kamil

http://SQLPlayer.net

Comment: So what's the solution .

Comment: Yes I have seen the execution plan and optimised to the best. As you mentioned though there is a max logic check it's taking time to query and filter the data.

Comment: The solution is to redesign a bit the current query and/or structure. I understand that there might be some logic but if you want to avoid scan all tables - must find incremental (id) marker or data-market to filtering data initially. Sorry, I can't give you ready solution as I don't know structure (including indexes) and statistics of tables.